# Is there any issues if i placeed Solr sever in same magent host

Tags: apache, magento, solr, jetty, hosting

I'm working with Magento & Solr4.6.0.

Its working fine for me

1. Auto suggestions
2. Spell corrections
3. Getting results from Solr server

& now i can able to get my products very less time.

I have one Small doubt I'm planning to place the all files in my Server before that i want know about some of the things.

**--->** If i'm running solr server in same server(i mean along with magento) is there any issues with this like performance Solr/Magento , Load time...etc

**--->** If i'm running the solr server form some other server means its there any +Ve/_Ve

Any ideas Please share with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Solr you are reducing Mysql load. Also due to weight concept in Solr you get better search results.

Well if your server is good enough( not at thresh hold with present traffic ) then you will not need additional server to run Solr.